# CREATE DATABASE or ALTER DATABASE failed because the resulting cumulative database size would exceed your licensed limit

Tags: sql-server

I think the size limit of the database is causing problems with our eCommerce website.

I was looking at the errors in Event Viewer on the server and the vast majority of errors I see belong to `MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS` and throw up :

> CREATE DATABASE or ALTER DATABASE failed because the resulting cumulative database size would exceed your licensed limit of 10240 MB per database.

I checked the size of the database and got 38402.44MB (38.4GB) - it only has .20MB free space.

I am trying to find out if I need to upgrade the database ?

Comment: SQL Server **Express** has a **10 GB** size limit on each database - if you need more, you need to buy a license for SQL Server Standard

Comment: Sql express doesnt allow more than 10240

Comment: thanks for the reply ! So will my database still work even if it goes past the 10GB limit on Express Edtion ? but cause errors ? Maybe thats what I am experiencing

Comment: is it expensive to get the hosting company to provide SQL Standard ? do i have any other options like compacting the database?